# Error messages are not translated

Tags: 7

We have successfully build a multilingual Drupal website, the only thing that isn't being translated yet are the error messages.

We have the default Drupal 6 contact form on the website. All the field labels are translated correctly including the "Send" button.

However, when someone just tries to submit the form without completing the fields, the error message always show in English.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to download the translation file of the language and it was fixed by importing it through the "translate interface" area of the Drupal backend.